# Long Android TextView pushes other views off-screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've got two TextViews side-by-side. TextView1 has a varying length of text, and TextView2 always says "+#". When TextView1 gets long however, it pushes TextView2 off screen. Any ideas how to fix this? Here's my layout code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you intend for the parent view to be a RelativeLayout, or a LinearLayout?  You're specifying android:orientation="horizontal" and orientations are only valid for LinearLayout.  Also, it would help if you could clarify what the expected behavior is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is actually something I've tried to solve for a while now. Unfortunately, the method others have suggested - using `layout_weight` inside `LinearLayout` - doesn't actually work; however, I've found a solution for you!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TextView2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With the above block, we use a `RelativeLayout` in order to align the first `TextView` to the left of the second `TextView`. We also align the second `TextView` to the right side of the parent `ViewGroup`. Finally, we add `android:gravity="left"` to the parent `ViewGroup` in order to align all of the `TextView`'s to the left.

This results in both `TextView`'s being side by side - regardless of the first `TextView`'s length. If you would like the first `TextView` to have multiple lines, simply remove the `android:ellipsize="end"` tag.

Hopefully this is your expected outcome!

Comment: Best answer ever! I was looking for this for two hours :)

Comment: @EvanBashir `layout_weight` should work.  It is important to note that if you are using weights, you need to set at either `layout_height` or `layout_width` to 0dp.  If you don't, the layout won't adjust the child views widths.

Comment: @Justin Your comment is irrelevant to the question. Yes, `layout_weight` does work inside a `linear_layout`; however, using `layout_weight` to accomplish what the poster is requesting does not work.

Comment: This works but it fix everything to the far right while I need this to be on the Left of the parent RelativeLayout... any help?

Comment: @Matteo Without more detail, it's hard to know exactly what you mean; however, can't you just flip the logic in the layout above to achieve the opposite result?

Comment: I think it's pretty much clear: the two inner layouts gets anchored to the right of the parent, even if the RelativeLayout has a gravity="left" attribute. I tried to flip the attributes but nothing changed

Comment: @Matteo please submit a new question, as I cannot properly evaluate the situation without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: For me `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TextView2"` didn't work. I replaced it with `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView2"` and that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with weight attributs on child views

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Here are screenshots, so you can see how it behaves with small and long text.

[image: Example 1: Small text]

[image: Example 2: Very long text]

**Here is XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rectangle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="70dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size16"
            />
    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scrollView">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Action 1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Action 2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAction1" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your TextView weight 1 and make its width/height "0dp"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/random_string" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```